Screen orientation in Ubuntu Frame
I have followed some instructions online to try to flip my screen orientation from landscape to portrait, but it seems the ubuntu-frame does not recognize it.
Here is my display config:
layouts:
  default:
    cards:
    - card-id: 0
      DisplayPort-1:
        # (disconnected)

      HDMI-A-1:
        # (disconnected)

      DisplayPort-2:
        # This output supports the following modes: 1920x1080@60.0, 1920x1080@59.9,
        # 1920x1080@30.0, 1920x1080@30.0, 1920x1080@50.0, 1920x1080@25.0, 1280x1024@60.0,
        # 1440x900@59.9, 1280x800@59.8, 1280x720@60.0, 1280x720@59.9, 1280x720@50.0,
        # 1024x768@60.0, 800x600@60.3, 800x600@56.2, 720x576@50.0, 720x480@60.0,
        # 720x480@59.9, 640x480@66.7, 640x480@60.0, 640x480@59.9, 720x400@70.1
        #
        # Uncomment the following to enforce the selected configuration.
        # Or amend as desired.
        #
        state: enabled  # {enabled, disabled}, defaults to enabled
        mode: 1080x1920@60.0    # Defaults to preferred mode
        position: [0, 0]        # Defaults to [0, 0]
        orientation: right # {normal, left, right, inverted}, defaults to normal
        scale: 1
        group: 0        # Outputs with the same non-zero value are treated as a single display

      HDMI-A-2:
        # (disconnected)

      DisplayPort-3:
        # (disconnected)

      HDMI-A-3:
        # (disconnected)

  side_by_side:
    cards:
    # a list of cards (currently matched by card-id)

    - card-id: 0
      DisplayPort-1:
        # (disconnected)

      HDMI-A-1:
        # (disconnected)

      DisplayPort-2:
        # This output supports the following modes: 1920x1080@60.0, 1920x1080@59.9,
        # 1920x1080@30.0, 1920x1080@30.0, 1920x1080@50.0, 1920x1080@25.0, 1280x1024@60.0,
        # 1440x900@59.9, 1280x800@59.8, 1280x720@60.0, 1280x720@59.9, 1280x720@50.0,
        # 1024x768@60.0, 800x600@60.3, 800x600@56.2, 720x576@50.0, 720x480@60.0,
        # 720x480@59.9, 640x480@66.7, 640x480@60.0, 640x480@59.9, 720x400@70.1
        #
        # Uncomment the following to enforce the selected configuration.
        # Or amend as desired.
        #
        state: enabled  # {enabled, disabled}, defaults to enabled
        mode: 1080x1920@60.0    # Defaults to preferred mode
        position: [0, 0]        # Defaults to [0, 0]
        orientation: right     # {normal, left, right, inverted}, defaults to normal
        scale: 1
        group: 0        # Outputs with the same non-zero value are treated as a single display

      HDMI-A-2:
        # (disconnected)

      DisplayPort-3:
        # (disconnected)

      HDMI-A-3:
        # (disconnected) 

I tried restarting it several times, used different orientations, resolutions but it stays the same.
I am using ubuntu-frame on top of my desktop 22.04LTS release.
Obviously I wanted to post on Ubuntu Frame Discourse but it says it's not technical support and I cannot create a new topic.
